# Magento 2 Leverage Browser Caching for Images, CSS and JS not any effect

Tags: magento2, .htaccess, browser

As in Magento 1 to increase the page speed score and Y-slow score we have used 
Leverage Browser Caching for Images, CSS and JS  code in .htaccess file but same script in Magento2 is not working.

below is the code of browser cache:

```
# Leverage browser caching using mod_expires #
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 days"
</IfModule>
# End of Leverage browser caching using mod_expires #
```

Why Magento 2 is not considering this code.?

If anything is wrong in code please share the code so we can optimize the code.

Comment: are you using shared hosting?

Comment: No,we are using AWS dedicated EC2.

Comment: you can try this one 
 https://fishpig.co.uk/magento/optimisation/leverage-browser-caching/

Comment: This is also not working.

Comment: do you have apache mod_expires?

Answer (score 2):

I had also faced the similar issue, even after updating .htaccess caching was not applied to files. Enable mode expires module and restart apache2, fixed issue.

```
sudo a2enmod expires
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following at the following:

**root > .htaccess file**

```
# Leverage browser caching using mod_expires #
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 days"
</IfModule>
# End of Leverage browser caching using mod_expires #
```

It will be clear the Leverage browser aching issue.

Comment: The steps you suggest for increasing the Magento 2 speed right?